# Looking for the best speech trainer capability for Spanish

Tags: online-learning, speaking, spanish

I'm trying to find the best app (mobile or desktop) with Spanish oral testing capabilities that allow for custom content. I've found that Rosetta Stone's speech recognition is pretty good but there's no way to create custom content. Memrise also has oral testing functionality (lower quality than RS IMO) but then I don't see where this can be used in their Decks companion app, where Decks allows for the creation of custom content.

At this point I'm thinking my only recourse is to develop something myself using the Google speech to text API.